# How to find more (maybe: all) natural isomorphisms with vector space and tensor constructions

Tags: linear-transformations, tensor-products, duality-theorems, natural-transformations

**Background:** I am refreshing my knowledge of tensor dualities to catch up with some physical applications.

**Example 1:** I am aware that $\mbox{Hom}(V, \mbox{Hom}(W,U))$ is naturally isomorphic to
$\mbox{Hom} (V\otimes W, U)$ and a linear $f\colon V\to \mbox{Hom}(W,U)$ is in a natural way identical to a linear $g\colon V\otimes W \to U$.

**Example 2:** I understand the applications of this for multilinear forms. For example, there is natural isomorphism between linear functions $f\colon V\otimes W \to {\mathbb K}$ and linear functions $g\colon V \to W^*$. Using a symmetric natural transformation, this also is naturally isomorphic to linear functions of the type $h\colon W \to V^*$.

**Approaching my question:** Now I became curious. The situation looks to me that there is some general theorem for moving back and forth components of a tensor products left and right of the linear mapping arrow $\to$ or, equivalently, $\mbox{Hom}$ functor in the vategory of vector spaces (or: finite vector spaces).

**Conjecture 1:** I can push a left-side tensor factor to the right-side by adding a dualization and I probably get a naturally isomorphic space. More precisely: The space of functions of type
$V_1 \otimes \ldots \otimes V_k \to W_1 \otimes \ldots \otimes W_l$ is naturally isomorphic to the space of functions of type $V_2 \otimes \ldots \otimes V_k \to V_1^* \otimes W_1 \otimes \ldots \otimes W_l$

**Conjecture 2:** I can pull a right-side tensor factor to the left-side by deleting (or, maybe, also adding? not sure?!?) dualization. *Removing* an *existing* dualization star should work. *Adding* a further dualization star *should(?)* work as well, at least if the component is finite dimensional, due to the natural isomorphism $V \cong V^{**}$ for finite dimensional vector spaces.

**Question:** To me it looks like there is a more general theorem for moving tensor product components (with or without dualization star) from one side of the $\mbox{Hom}$ to the other side and staying naturally isomorphic while doing so.

**What is known there? Is there a more general theorem? How does it look like?**

And if there is: Is there, among all of these equivalent, naturally isomorphic forms, some form of *generic* or *normal* form?

I am interested in the finite as well as the infinite dimensional case. I am focusing on *naturally* isomorphic scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For finite dimensional spaces, we have canonical isomorphism $\newcommand{\Hom}{\operatorname{Hom}}$ :
\begin{align}
\Hom(U,V) &\simeq U^*\otimes V \\
(U\otimes V)^* &\simeq U^*\otimes V^* \\
U^{**}&\simeq U
\end{align}
as well as canonical isomorphism for the associativity and commutativity of the tensor product.

From those we can derive other isomorphisms :
\begin{align}
\Hom(U\otimes V,W) &\simeq (U\otimes V)^*\otimes W\\
&\simeq U^*\otimes V^*\otimes W \\
&\simeq \Hom(U,V^*\otimes W)
\end{align}

Likewise :
\begin{align}
\Hom(U,V\otimes W) &\simeq U^*\otimes V\otimes W\\
&\simeq (U\otimes V^*)^*\otimes W \\
&\simeq \Hom(U\otimes V^*,W)
\end{align}
and :
\begin{align}
\Hom(U,\Hom(V,W)) &\simeq \Hom(U,V^*\otimes W) \\
&\simeq \Hom(U\otimes V,W)
\end{align}

From this set of canonical isomorphims, you can build all the canonical isomorphisms you want. I am not sure what kind of theorem you want to state/prove here.

Using those isomorphisms, we can put a space of the form :
$$\mathfrak V = \Hom(U_1 \otimes \ldots\otimes  U_i \otimes  V_1^* \otimes \ldots \otimes V_j^*,W_1\otimes \ldots\otimes W_k\otimes E_1^* \otimes \ldots \otimes E_n^*)$$
into any number of "normal" forms which are unique up to permutation of the factors :

1. Only tensor product, no $\Hom$ :
   $$\mathfrak V \simeq U_1^* \otimes \ldots \otimes U_i^* \otimes  V_1 \otimes \ldots \otimes V_j\otimes W_1\otimes \ldots \otimes W_k\otimes E_1^* \otimes \ldots \otimes E_n^*$$
2. No duality stars :
   $$\mathfrak V \simeq \Hom(U_1 \otimes \ldots \otimes U_i \otimes  E_1 \otimes \ldots \otimes E_n,W_1\otimes \ldots\otimes W_k\otimes  V_1 \otimes \ldots \otimes V_j)$$
3. No tensor product, only $\Hom$.
4. Many others

Comment: Cool. Precise answer. Exactly what I was looking for.